# Elastic Search across different indexes failing in a multi threaded scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, elasticsearch

I have a use case, where i need to fetch data from 5 different indexes , and then combine the result.Doing that serially is taking a lot of time.

I want to run the elastic searches in parallel and then combine the results.
I am using ExecutorService which spawns 5 different threads and fire the elastic query across different indices.

I have the RestHighLevelClient as a singleton.

I am getting the below error  : -

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed unexpectedly
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.closed(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onClosed(InternalIODispatch.java:71)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onClosed(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.disconnected(AbstractIODispatch.java:100)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionClosed(BaseIOReactor.java:279)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processClosedSessions(AbstractIOReactor.java:440)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:283)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

***If i create a new client per thread, this seems to work. But that is a performance hit.

```
private void createESClient() {
    try {
        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        int connectTimeout = 10000;
        int maxRetryTimeout = 60000;

        lowLevelClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host))
                .setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout).setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)).setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(maxRetryTimeout).build();
        client = new RestHighLevelClient(lowLevelClient);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How could i achieve parallelism without creating multiple clients ?

Comment: Please show code where you start several threads that use the same instance of `RestHighLevelClient`. ElasticSearch doc`umentation says that `RestHighLevelClient` **is** thread-safe: `The RestHighLevelClient is thread-safe. It is typically instantiated by the application at startup time or when the first request is executed.`

Comment: It was more of a silly mistake , i was doing 
 //DOIElasticSearchRestClient.close(); in every worker thread which was causing the issue. The issue is resolved now.